# How to wait for a value or until a fixed amount of time has elapsed using Reactive Extensions (Rx.Net)

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I want to wait (block) a thread until either a time has elapsed or another stream pumps a value, I thought the following might achieve this but it throws an exception because the first stream is empty,

```
 // class level subject manipulated by another thread...
 _updates = new Subject<Unit>();
 ...
 // wait for up to 5 seconds before carrying on...    
 var result = Observable.Timer(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5))
    .TakeUntil(_updates)
    .Wait();
```

How can I achieve the ability to block for up to 5 seconds or until the other stream pumps a value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Observable.Timeout` like this:

```
 var result = _updates.Take(1).Timeout(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5)).Wait();
```

I use `Take(1)` because timeout expects sequence to complete, not just produce next value. On timeout it will throw `System.TimeoutException`.

If you don't want exception - you can use `Catch` to provide some value instead:

```
var result = _updates.Take(1).Timeout(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5))
    .Catch(Observable.Return(default(Unit))).Wait();
// should catch specific exception, not all
```

If your `Unit` is indeed that rx unit mentioned by @Shlomo - you can change it like this:

```
var result = _updates.Select(c => (Unit?) c).Take(1)
    .Timeout(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5)).Catch(Observable.Return((Unit?) null)).Wait();
```

or just catch that exception as usual.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but `default(Unit) == Unit.Default == new Unit()`, so `result` will always have the same value going forward.

Comment: @Shlomo not sure what you mean. If updates sequence produce a value - result will be that value, not a default. Also if unit is class - default(Unit) is null. Maybe OP means some specific Unit which I'm not aware about, but I treat Unit just as arbitrary class.

Comment: He's probably referring to System.Reactive.Unit, which is a struct, not a class. See http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#ObservableStart

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative if you don't want to deal with exceptions:

```
var _updates = new Subject<Unit>();

var result = Observable.Merge(
    _updates.Materialize(),
    Observable.Empty<Unit>()
       .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
       .Materialize()
   )
   .Take(1)
   .Wait();

switch (result.Kind)
{
    case NotificationKind.OnCompleted:
        //time's up, or someone called _updates.OnCompleted().
        break;
    case NotificationKind.OnNext:
        var message = result.Value;
        //Message received. Handle message
        break;
    case NotificationKind.OnError:
        var exception = result.Exception;
        //Exception thrown. Handle exception
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you create two tasks and then do a wait any? That would likely be the "easiest" way to achieve that.

```
var waitTask = new Task(() => Thread.Sleep(5000));
var messageTask = new Task(() => <listen for input and return>);

await Task.WhenAny(waitTask, messageTask);

<the rest of your code>
```

Edit: Title changed to specify React, answer probably wouldn't be applicable anymore.